# How do I work out the order in which I write my objects to the database?

Tags: .net, orm, datamapper, unit-of-work, data-mapping

I have written a rudimentary ORM mechanism based on the Data Mapper pattern(s) outlined by Martin Fowler. I have a Unit of Work that tracks which objects have been changed. Obviously, due to foreign keys and other db constraints, changes must be written to the tables in a specific order.

What solutions are available to determine the order in which I write the changes? Fowler hints at a 'topographical sort' in his PoEAA book.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by allowing objects to implement an interface with a single property called Tier. The processing done by the Unit of Work uses this to order updates and deletes via LINK.